# File explorer doesn't refresh automatically when files are added by some programs

Tags: windows-7

When I unzip a file into a new folder, the new folder doesn't show automatically in the folder. I have to click on the files pane and then the folder pane gets refreshed.

Also when I download a file to a folder, the file doesn't show up. I sort by date and it doesn't show. I have to click on another folder and then click on the download folder for the file to show up. Is this normal behavior in Windows 7?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just at the bottom of the folder? Change the view to details, and then try it and see if it shows at the bottom of the list. It does not insert in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it is 'normal' behavior per se , but I believe it ties to the fact that starting with Windows Vista (and continuing into Windows 7) the NTFS (The filesystem your hard drive gets formatted to to run Windows) is now a transactional file system. This means that changes to the file system are not committed into being 'real' until all changes are completed and it is like a switch making all changes appear at once. This is the first actual production use of a transactional filesystem, so this is where my finger is pointed, albeit a very 'cool' and useful technique, there are glitches like this showing up.

My suggestion to you would be to run a complete disk check and hopefully that will get everything back into sync and refreshing properly.

"start button" -> "computer" -> right click "C:\" drive -> "propertied" -> "tools" tab -> "check now.." -> make sure "automatically fix filesystem errors" is checked

you will have to "schedule" it and restart your computer and let it do the work.

Good luck

Comment: Transactions aren't automatic, though -- they must be initiated by the program as far as I know.

Comment: I do think your right @grawity... but I am unsure as to which program he is using to do the unzipping, I would assume the default Windows utility.. and then from that point I am unsure as to how Windows would handle that process. Transactional FS is one of the biggest reasons I can see things not refreshing or appearing. This is not the first time I have heard of this happening, yet only on Vista and 7 machines. If it turns out to be something else I would love to know about it!